# Artifact shows on usage of custom color for JTextPane Background Color

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

After using custom made color:

```
Color bg = new Color(0f,0f,0f,0.5f);
```

for a `JTextPane` background I can see that background of `JTextPane` is shown with parts of background that comes from `Jlabel` that includes `JTextPane` in it.

Picture of what's happening:

[image: Image of problem]

So the bottom part of `JTextPane` background is OK, but the top one that's behind a text is having some issues.

How can I fix it? Have I made mistake by using custom color for simple transparent background for `JTextPane`?

Code for this part of the program:

```
t = new JTextPane();
SimpleAttributeSet style = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(style , StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
StyleConstants.setForeground(style , Color.white);
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Times new Roman");
StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 20);
StyleConstants.setBold(style, true);
t.setParagraphAttributes(style,true);
t.setText(" " + text.getT1().get(0).toUpperCase());
t.setOpaque(true);
Color bg = new Color(0f,0f,0f,0.5f);
t.setBackground(bg);
t.setEditable(false);
t.setBounds(250, 400, 300, 50);
animation.add(t);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swing doesn't support transparent backgrounds properly. Swing expects the component to be fully opaque or not based on the setOpaque(....) property.

When using transparent background you need to make sure the background of the parent container is painted first before the background of the transparent component is painted.

Check out [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information on this process.

You can customize you component and do your own painting with code like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};

panel.setOpaque(false); // background of parent will be painted first
panel.setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 20) );
frame.add(panel);
```

Or the easier approach is to use the `AlphaContainer` class provided in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a similar problem. You need to have at least the container of the JTextPane made opaque with no transparency. Otherwise Swing calculates very wrongly the background. You might report that as a bug I think.